# Какое число ближе к диапазону

Tags: c#

Есть два диапазона `2200..2500` и  `2300..2400`. Допустим есть число `2350`. Как определить в какой диапазон оно входит?

Comment: Что значит "ближе"? В какой диапазон попадает?

Comment: изменил вопрос .

Comment: Понятнее не стало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на LINQ:

```
var num = 22130;

var firstRange = Enumerable.Range(22000, 100);
var secondRange = Enumerable.Range(22100, 100);

var inFirstRange = first.Contains(n => n == num);
var inSecondRange = first.Contains(n => n == num);
```

Просто условие:

```
var num = 22130;
var inFirstRange = num >= 22000 && num <= 22099;
var inSecondRange = num >= 22100 && num <= 22199;
```

Можете реализовать метод проверки диапазона:

```
bool TestRange(int num, int left, int right)
{
  return num >= left && num <= right;
}
```